# MQL5 IsNewBar function ignore 1970.01.01

Tags: mql5

i am working with mql5 and want to have a little function to detect a new bar.
Seems not to be a hard point, smile ...
But i am really confused about my function.

My goal is:
I want to have a bool function that give back true if a new bar is opened.
During initialisation / starting an EA first Tick will be nothing, so 1970.01.01 with value 0 should happen and be ignored. I really want to wait until the first complete new bar is opened.

```js
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| IsNewBar
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool IsNewBar(ENUM_TIMEFRAMES m_timeframe){
   static datetime lastbar;
   datetime currentbar = (datetime)SeriesInfoInteger(_Symbol,m_timeframe,SERIES_LASTBAR_DATE);
   if(lastbar != currentbar){
      lastbar = currentbar;
      // if lastbar is 1970.01.01 (=value 0) ... This will happen during start an EA in the middle of a bar.
      if(lastbar != 0){
         Print("true");
         return true;
      }else{
         Print("false");
         return false;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

This is my testing code to activate the function:

```js
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick(){
   if(IsNewBar(PERIOD_M1)==true){
      Print("x");
   }
}
```

It seems like completely ignored the first Tick 1970.01.01 thing.
I did not figure out where my problem is.

Please help! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem of my original code.

If anyone is interesting in, here is the working function:

```js
bool IsNewBar(ENUM_TIMEFRAMES m_timeframe){
   static datetime lastbar;
   datetime currentbar = (datetime)SeriesInfoInteger(_Symbol,m_timeframe,SERIES_LASTBAR_DATE);
   
   if(lastbar != currentbar){
      if(lastbar == 0){
         lastbar = currentbar;
         return false;
      }else{
         lastbar = currentbar;
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do:

```
//Global:
datetime newBarTime;
//onInit:
newBarTime = iTime(0,0,0) + Periodseconds();
//on the run
if(TimeCurrent() >= newBarTime){
    newBarTime = iTime(0,0,0) + Periodseconds();
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code.
My goal is to have a stand alone function for this.

Just in this moment i understand the problem of my function and fixed it.
Some days distance helped me in this case, smile.

Thank you very much for your try to help.